# I can't get the closest matches right here...How can i implement difflib right here in a right order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, difflib

When i am typing "rainn", i want to get results for "rain".Here's what i've tried - but there is no success

```
import mysql.connector
from difflib import get_close_matches

con = mysql.connector.connect(
user = <user>,
password = <password>,
host = <host>,
database = <db>
)

cursor = con.cursor()

word = input('Enter a word: ')

query = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Dictionary WHERE Expression = "%s" '% word)
results = cursor.fetchall()


if results:
   for result in results:
       print(results[1])

if len(get_close_matches(word,results))>0:
    print(get_close_matches(word,results))
else:
    print('no word found!')
```

Comment: One thing worth mentioning: I hope that SQL connection data is all fake for security purposes. That said: We don't need to see the sql code, we need to see what `word` and `results` are at the time you try to get matches, and describe _how_ the result is different from what you want

Comment: I'm seeing a match when I manually create a list for results. I would check your results variable.
`from difflib import get_close_matches

results = ['rain', 'Rain']
word = 'rainn'

print(get_close_matches(word,results, cutoff=0.6))`